# How to use current user certificate by IIS

Tags: iis, certificate, x509certificate

I've handled a problem, that my IIS server uses Local Machine certificates, but I want it to use Current User certificates. I can't import certificate because it's protected by private key.

How can I switch type of certificates, using by IIS?

Comment: It is impossible. Server certificates must be installed under Local Machine's MY store, or Web Hosting, https://github.com/Microsoft/IIS.Administration/issues/40 There is no room for discussion.

Comment: @LexLi but is there some another way to use current user certificate? I've tried to set `var store = new X509Store( StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);` but this didn't work too.